# MS Visual Studio 2005 C++ exception handling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I have a C++ application built in MS Visual Studio 2005 that links to a 3rd party library. For a certain input, the application crashes in the 3rd party library (apparently somewhere in realloc.c; so has to be a memory issue of some kind). I ran in release because the input is huge. So I ran until it crashes and then choose to debug. While I separately debug the guilty function, I was hoping to use some exception handling to prevent the application from crashing and instead exit cleanly. So I used something like:

```
try {
   //- call 3rd party application function that fails
}
catch(...) {
   //- handle exception or whatever
   Logger::Fatal("Fatal error: Exiting...");
   return false;
}
```

But to my surprise the application still crashes! I was expecting to see it display the error message since I've presumably caught all exceptions with the ellipsis (...); what am I missing here? I even tried setting /EHca (was /EHsc) in Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Configuration -> Enable Exception Handling. On a related note about what might be causing the problem, is the following usage correct?

```
my_class* mc[] = {nil, nil, nil};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    mc[i] = new my_class();
    //-Do stuff with mc[i]
    if (mc[i] != nil) {
       delete mc[i];
       mc[i] = nil;
    }
}
```

The failure to get the exception handling working is rather puzzling. I would certainly appreciate ideas/insights from the C++ gurus out there. BTW, the same problem also occurs on Linux (RHEL5) but I am currently trying to get the exception handling to work on Windows.

NOTE: When I let it debug after the crash. I do get an "Access violation..unable to read location" message. With this updated info, I was hoping something in C++ would still work on both Windows & Linux for such crashes.

Comment: It seems like you are expecting an `c` function to throw an exception here.

Comment: hmm... its possible the 3rd party application calls a C function which is the guilty one. But do you mean it won't work? Then how can I handle such exceptions from within C++?

Comment: Unless you know that there is an exception being thrown,How can you catch it? Maybe the 3rd party library is just crashing without throwing any exceptions.You need to make sure that the 3rd party library emits exceptions.

Comment: But isn't that what the ellipsis is supposed to do.. to catch all kinds of exceptions, even crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried catching the crash by calling [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(v=VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. Are there any standard handlers that may work on Linux as well? Since this appears to be MS Visual Studio specific.

Comment: What I gave you is an OS level exception handler, it has nothing to do with C or C++ or Visual Studio. Not sure if it will work, but it might. And yes, it is Windows only. I recommend that instead of trying to workaround what seems to be a serious problem in your application, you spend some time debugging and fixing your memory problem. On Linux, I'm certain Valgrind can help.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. Ofcourse I will debug it.. but since it happens in the 3rd party application, I was looking to commit the exception handler so that it doesn't crash on users while I debug the issue.

Comment: This is C code, there is no exception handling in the C++ style, so you have to give up the idea of using try/catch as that will never work. On Linux you can trap the signal that causes the crash and the exit gracefully, see signal.h.

Answer (score 0):

As Miguel suggested, a correct way to solve your problem is probably to use `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. But I'd like to explain your phenomena in details nevertheless.

First of all, not all the program "crashes" are related to exceptions. For instance, CRT may trigger program termination upon errors, such as invalid element access in a `vector`, or a pure virtual destructor call. If you want to cover those cases as well - see `set_unexpected`, `set_terminate` and etc.

Besides of this, `catch` block may only catch exceptions thrown from the appropriate code block. OTOH there may be functions that are called elsewhere, such as window procedures (if applicable), other threads and etc.

Now, regarding your problem. Let's first realize why things like `catch(...)` may catch things like access violation, and etc, and why this does not always happen (like in your case).

Windows provides its own exception handling mechanism - SEH, structured exception handling. It's far superior to C++ exception handling. In addition hardware interrupts (caused by CPU) are automatically "converted" into SEH exceptions, so that the code that uses SEH handles both software exceptions and hardware failures.

**Microsoft C++ compilers actually implement C++ exceptions via SEH**. That is `throw` is implemented via `RaiseException` with specifying C++ - specific exception code and parameters, `catch` is a C++ - specific wrapper for `__except`, and for every object with destructor the compiler generates something similar to `__finally` block. And this also works vice-versa. When a non-C++ exception is raised - the same code generated for C++ exceptions is executed.

In addition there are so-called compiler exception handling options that affect both the compiler exception handling code generation, and its behavior in runtime. They are called exception handling models:

- **synchronous**. The compiler generates a code that is guaranteed to work correctly only if exceptions are raised explicitly. This includes `throw` statments, and all the "foreign" functions whose code is not visible to the compiler (in some variations - only C++ foreign functions). In particular reading from memory is considered "safe".
- **asynchronous**. The compiler is not allowed to assume anything about where exceptions may arise. Hence it generates the code that should work correctly even if exception is arises from accessing a memory address.

In addition, CRT code that's invoked in `catch (...)` **deliberately ignores non-C++ exceptions, unless asynchronous EH model is choosen**.

So that if you want `catch (...)` to catch non-C++ exceptions - you **must** choose the asynchronous EH model.

Once I've written an [article on the codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22801/Drivers-Exceptions-and-C), after I had a related problem in driver development. It explains all this in details.